# Weather map for India including monthly averages?

Tags: online-resources, india, maps, weather-and-climate

Where can one find an online weather map of India, including monthly averages of temp & rain, as well as live forecast?

Comment: Do you mean for a specific city or for the whole country?

Comment: for every capitol or every big area

Answer (score 2):

You can have it here:
http://www.imd.gov.in/main_new.htm

For Chennai there is also this other one:
http://www.kea.metsite.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Yahoo site:
http://in.weather.yahoo.com/india/delhi/new-delhi-2295019/

Answer (score 1):

You can find weather details of all major cities of India [here](http://www.mapsofindia.com/weather/) or [here](http://www.weatherforecastmap.com/india/).

Answer (score 0):

For monthly averages you can use http://www.weatherbase.com/weather/city.php3?c=IN&refer=&name=India